# How to restore my old pebble stone driveway?

Tags: patio, driveway, pressure-washer

My driveway and patio is all made of this pebble stone / pebblecrete / pebble dash / chattahoochee from the 70’s. It’s in pretty bad cosmetic shape. I don’t have it in my budget to rip it out and replace it now, but wondering if there are ways to restore or paint/stain over it?

It has some discolored stains that haven’t come off with pressure or soft washing.

**Things I’ve tried: pressure washing with concrete cleaner, scrubbing with degreasers, soft washing with sodium hypochlorite**

https://imgur.com/a/GtMplKv

Comment: It has weathered beyond its useful life.   It will not be able to be restored.   You may inquire about coating with epoxy, but that too may not be viable.

Comment: Diluted Muriatic acid could work. Try it in small spot

Comment: Looks like an exposed aggregate finish.  I don't see anything too bad, except a few spots where the aggregate has gone.  That rust-colored stain could be rust, or it could be some kind of organic tannin—like some kind of acorn or similar sat there too long.  OP, have you tried viegar or bleach (or an organic stain remover, like for bloodstains and such)?